# How does a flexbox expand to it's child on overflow?

Tags: html, css, overflow, flexbox

I have a flexbox layout.

The html is as follows:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">Content</div>
    <div class="column">Content2</div>
    <div class="column">Content2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">Content</div>
    <div class="column">Content2</div>
    <div class="column">Content2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.grid {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #eee;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  background-color: #ddd;
  align-items: stretch;
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.column {
  flex: 1 0 20em;
  padding: 0.2em;
  border: 2px solid lightblue;
  /*background-color: hsla(0, 100%, 80%, 50%);*/
}
```

(see https://jsfiddle.net/bz71qptu/1/)

In the previous code, the `.box` element does not expand to the width of its children. How do I make it do this?

#### Edit

I have added an example of what I am hoping to achieve visually to the jsfiddle

#### Edit 2

I needed to change the question slightly to fit my particular issue. The parent element is aligned with `flex-direction: column` which means that using `min-width` doesn't seem to work. The `min-width` solution would be perfect without this.

#### Edit 3

I'm very thankful to everyone for helping, but I'm not sure I've exactly captured the behaviour I wanted to in my example, and even with all the advice I've been given I can't seem to make it do what I want. Here is a much better [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bz71qptu/1/), if you look at this I've put borders up to show where everything is. I've read through the answers to see if I can adapt them to my situation, but I can't quite see it. I apologise if this fiddle is already answered.

Comment: Check browser support for the `content` value.

Comment: According to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) No browsers support content. Is there another way?

Comment: It may be that current browsers cannot handle what I'm asking for - in that case could I do it with an extra wrapping element?

Comment: After a lot of effort I believe that this is not possible with current css/browsers

Comment: **Solution** Not an answer to the question, but my solution was to allow flex to size the child elements and then resize the parent to match on each draw. Obviously this would be better handled by the layout engine (probably an order of magnitude faster) but since my code doesn't have animations I can get away with it.

Answer (score 3):

**Revised Answer**

Your revised question changes the `flex-direction` from `row` to `column`.

With this adjustment, the `flex` property applied to `.box` is no longer relevant for your purposes, as it now handles vertical sizing. In other words, with `column` the `flex` property controls height not width.

As I mentioned in the comments, however, adding `overflow: auto` to `.box` seems to work perfectly (tested in Chrome, FF and IE11).

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ck8gtpvg/)

You mentioned in your comments that it breaks the layout engine. The layout broke for me, as well in jsFiddle. Just hit [RUN] it again.

Ever since jsFiddle launched their upgrade a few days/weeks(?) ago it's been causing some confusion, as it now caches code. You may need to clear jsFiddle cookies (go to *chrome://settings/cookies* in your browser) or run revised code again after loading.

---

**Original Answser**

Instead of `content` for the `flex-basis` value, try `auto` or `0`.

[The `content` value isn't supported yet.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis#Browser_compatibility)

In fact, maybe simply `flex: 1` will work for you.

See here:

- [CSS-Tricks ~ Common Values for `flex`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/)
- [W3C Flexbox Spec ~ Common Values for `flex`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common)

Comment: I've removed the confusing `flex-basis: content` and replaced it with 'auto'. As you can see the problem is still there - the child overflows, but the parent does not.

Comment: Try adding `overflow: auto;` to `.box`

Comment: That well and truly breaks chromium's layout engine :) (try it)

Answer (score 1):

- **class `.box` is a flexbox container and a flexed child of class
  `.container`**

`display: flex` makes it act as a flexbox container

`flex: 1 0 auto` defines how it behaves as a child (of `.container`)

- **class `.element` is a flexed child of class `.box`**

`display: flex` makes `.element` act as a flexbox container and yields no effect in your fidde (only when `.element` has children)

`flex: 1 0 auto` defines how it behaves as a child (of `.box`)

As you have not defined any sizes but `1000em` for class `.element`, `overflow: auto` for class `.container` and `flex-shrink: 0` (in `flex: 1 0 auto`) for both class `.box` and `.element` all elements react on the defined `1000em` and can only grow to `1000em`.

Change both `flex: 1 0 auto` to `flex: 1` (defaults to `flex: 1 1 auto`) and your question has been answered!

**Tiny update**: `.element` change to `flex: 1; min-width: 1000em`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/renevanderlende/581hj8hj/7/)

Comment: I don't want the child to shrink. I want it to overflow and create scrollbars, but I want the parent background to match the size of the child.